# What causes triboluminescence in quartz?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I have already read [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21831/why-does-separating-plastic-from-a-cough-drop-create-flashes) about triboluminescence but it doesn't really cover my question.

I am trying to understand what causes quartz crystals to glow when mechanical pressure is applied to them. ([Here is a short video of the effect I'm talking about](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLkIoB5Iv5o)). Most of what I have read has stated that triboluminescence is caused by separation of charge when a crystal is broken leading to ionization of nitrogen in the air (i.e. wintergreen lifesavers). For quartz, this doesn't seem to be the case. There is no (visible) fracturing and I can rub two quartz crystals together repeatedly to get the effect over and over. Originally, I thought that the mechanical pressure provided some sort of activation energy that allowed electrons to jump bands but I can't seem to find anything to support that in my solid state textbook or in research articles.

So, **what is the mechanism that produces light in triboluminescent quartz?**

<sub>Bonus points if you can point me towards a textbook or article on the subject. Everything I've found has been rather lacking.</sub>